# How to label shapes in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a for loop in tikz which draws n circles
I want to name them A, B, C...etc
How do I do that?
can I create a char array or something similar and use it within the label `{$ $}`

also if I do

```
{$\x*\y$};
```

the labels appear as `1*1` and `1*2`
how can I actually multiply to get labels as `1` and `2`.

```
\foreach \x in {1,...,2}
    \foreach \y in {1,...,2}
    {
        \node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, draw, inner sep=\hex cm] (hex\x*\y*4) at 
        (\x*\pi*4.2,\y*\pi*1.6 + 0.8*\pi) {};
        \node[zoneMaster] at (\x*\pi*4.2,\y*\pi*1.6 + 0.8*\pi) {};  
        \node[zoneMaster] [minimum size=0.7cm, fill=Black,text=White] at (\x*\pi*4.2,\y*\pi*1.6 + 0.8*\pi) {$\x*\y$};
    }
```

Comment: Could you turn your snippet into a [minimal working examples](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)? This helps people to answer you.

Comment: For the first part of your question `\tikz\foreach\l[count=\x from 0]in{A,...,H}\node[circle,draw]at(\x,0){$\l$};` should show the way. Alternatively you can use `\let\pgfforAlpha=\pgffor@Alpha` (with the appropriate `@` catcode change) and then `\tikz\foreach\x in{1,...,8}\node[circle,draw]at(\x-1,0){$\pgfforAlpha{\x}$};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use  `\pgfmathsetmacro` or `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` to compute real or integer values:

[image]

### Notes:

- The style `zoneMaster` was not defined so I have defined it to be an empty style.
- The macro `\pi` is for the greek letter of the mathematical constant, it is not a numerical value.  In `pgfmath` you use `pi` for the numerical value.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\tikzset{zoneMaster/.style={}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
\foreach \x in {1,...,2}
    \foreach \y in {1,...,2}
    {
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\X}{0.5*\x*pi*4.2}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\Y}{\y*pi*1.6 + 0.8*pi}%
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Label}{\x*\y*4}%
        \node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, draw, inner sep=1cm] (hex\Label) at 
        (\X,\Y) {};
        \node[zoneMaster] at (\X,\Y) {};  
        \node[zoneMaster] [minimum size=0.7cm, fill=black,text=white] at (\X,\Y) {$\x*\y$};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: why does  \pgfmathsetmacro{} return float value? can I make it integer?

Comment: @user494461: Use `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` to obtain integer values as I have done in the example for the `\Label`.